# Learning Pivoting in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, pivot

I feel that this should be simple, but all the pivots I find seem to be more complicated than what I am looking for, so any help or re-direction would be much appreciated.

I have ‘ID_code’ and ‘product_name’ and I am looking for mismatched product names and have them put next to each other in a row as opposed to in a column like this:

```
Select distinct ID_Code, product_name
From table
Where ID_Code in
(Select ID_Code from table
Group by ID_Code
Having count(distinct product_name) <> 1)
```

I would like a table set out as

ID_Code     Product_name1  Product_name2  Product_name3

Thanks very much, and have a Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1):

This should remove the duplicates but still returns one result if the product_name has a match.

```
;with testdata as(
SELECT '1' as ID_Code, 'bike' as product_name
UNION ALL SELECT '1', 'biker'
UNION ALL SELECT '1', 'bike'
UNION ALL SELECT '2', 'motorbike'
UNION ALL SELECT '2', 'motorbike'
UNION ALL SELECT '2', 'motorbike'
UNION ALL SELECT '2', 'motrbike'
UNION ALL SELECT '2', 'motorbiker'
)

--added this section to return distinct products
,cte as(
SELECT * FROM testdata d1
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM testdata d2
)

SELECT --DISTINCT   --Use DISTINCT here if need to return just one line per ID_Code 

    ID_Code
    ,product_name = STUFF((SELECT ', ' +
                        --Added this to track product_names for each ID_Code
                        t2.product_name + '_' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_Code ORDER BY product_name) as varchar(100))
      FROM cte t2
      WHERE t2.ID_Code = cte.ID_Code
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')

FROM cte
```

Example here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=53900d07c32682af6b60f2bb565ef928)

More info about [INTERSECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) should this not be what works in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output appears to be somewhat inflexible, because we may not know exactly how many columns/products would be needed.  Instead, I recommend and rolling up the mismatched products into a CSV string for output.

```
SELECT
    ID_Code,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + t2.product_name
      FROM yourTable t2
      WHERE t1.ID_Code = t2.ID_Code
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') products
FROM your_table t1
GROUP BY
    ID_Code
HAVING
    MIN(product_name) <> MAX(product_name);    -- index friendly
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, SQL is telling me I have an incorrect syntax near the keyword Order, in your answer.      Also is it possible to get the answers in separate columns so that I can compare them? In reality, there will be under 4 product names. Some would be null when there is only 1 mismatch.

Comment: @Big_D Try using `ARRAY_AGG` instead, q.v. my updated answer.  I don't recommend the separate column idea.

Comment: Unfortunately my sql doesn’t have that function. Will look at getting it later.       Why is separate columns a bad idea?  Thanks for all your feedback!

Comment: @Big_D I updated my answer with SQL Server code.  For whatever reason, I thought you were using Postgres.  My query should run now.